# jquery conflicting with jquery

Tags: jquery

i want to use both jquery script in php page but both jquery script are conflicting to each others

**here my code**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="topslider/lib/jquery.jcarousel.min.js"></script>
```

**Conflicting Jquery Script**

```
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
 <script>
  $(function() {
  $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker();
  });
  </script>
```

Comment: Try including the jquery library just once instead of twice as you're doing above.

Comment: As @asprin says above - remove this line: `<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>`

Comment: @WheretheresaWill i replace 1.4.2 jquery to <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script> now both are working thanks

Answer (score 2):

Your best bet is to only include jQuery **once**. I would certainly steer well clear of v1.4.2, which has been out of date for a couple of years. Even 1.8.3 is a few versions back, perhaps look at using the latest (1.9.2). (And as leftclickben points out in the comments, there's a newer version of jQuery UI you can use as well, 1.10.1.)

So this would probably work, provided the carousel you're using is compatible with the latest:

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="topslider/lib/jquery.jcarousel.min.js"></script>
<script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jqueryui/1.10.1/jquery-ui.min.js"></script>
```

Note that there I've used the Google CDN for both jQuery and jQuery UI.

---

If you absolutely **must** include both copies of jQuery, you can, but I would strongly recommend avoiding it, and it requires that the plugins you're using are properly written (which is by no means guaranteed):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.4.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="topslider/lib/jquery.jcarousel.min.js"></script>
<script>
var jq142 = jQuery.noConflict(true);
</script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.8.3.js"></script>
<script src="http://code.jquery.com/ui/1.10.0/jquery-ui.js"></script>
```

Now, `jq142` refers to jQuery 1.4.2, and `jQuery` and `$` both refer to jQuery 1.8.3.

But again, I would avoid this. If you have plugins that require jQuery 1.4.2, I recommend finding replacements that are maintained.

Comment: @FarhanDharsi: (1.9.2, I misspoke) Assuming the plugins you're using are compatible with it, yes. Certainly jQuery UI 1.10 is compatible with jQuery 1.9.2. If the jcarousel plugin you're using isn't, then I'd find one that is (there are a **lot** of carousel plugins). And yes, you only have to include jQuery once, regardless of how many plugins you're also including.

Comment: @T.J.Crowder The latest UI is also 1.10.1, not 1.10.0 :-)

Answer (score 0):

So. In my point of view. You schould use only 1 jQuery src, and plugins.
I prefere newest version. like
https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js and plug ins to edit, manipulate, animate your work it like rotation, textillate, rotate. Perfect jquery editors are

```
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.3.1.js"></script>
<script src="https://raw.githubusercontent.com/wilq32/jqueryrotate/master/jQueryRotate.js"></script>
<script src="textillate.js"></script>
<script src="lettering.js"></script>
```

for me it's working absolutly fine.